# Query set based on specific hash value of it's members

Tags: redis, node-redis

This would be easy in most databases but not sure how to do this in redis. So here is how I'm adding members to a set:

```
 redis.sadd("usersRandom", userID);
 redis.hmset("users:"+userID, "socketID", socket.id, "hangoutId",hangoutIds, "language",languageName);
```

- The set `usersRandom` is a set of users
- Each `user` in this set has three hash values stored on it - `socketID`, `hangoutId`, `language`

I'd like to perform this:

```
 redis.spop("usersRandom");
```

HOWEVER, I'd like to pop only users with a specific `language` value.

---

The two ways I've come up with to do this are:

1. Return all members of the set `usersRandom` and then match them myself on the `language` key - then pop.
2. Create different sets based on `languages`. So I'd have numerous sets like `usersRandom_english`, `usersRandom_spanish` (those variable names could use some work). It seems messier, but maybe this is the best way with Redis.

Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

2 is the right direction. You could consider using a sorted set for all languages (assuming each user has one and only one language) to store user ids - use the score as a crude language indicator (e.g. English is score 1, Spanish is 2...). This will let to you do ranges by score (language) to get relevant ids.